# Unable to publish an update in google play console

Tags: react-native, android-studio, google-play

I have published an app and also published 3 updates after publishing that with the same app access credentials, but now when I'm trying to give an update it shows "Issue found: Login Credentials", but we have not changed anything, we are testing that app with the same credential which we have given in play-console it is working fine.

For that we also have open testing in playconsole in that, they are producing issues in app access.

Now how can we resolve this?

this is our login page

[image]